# SSIS Pkg with Script Task runs fine manually , but fails when deployed as a SQL Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

So I have an SSIS package that has many things - Script Task to Move Files, Exe Task to Unzip file, another task to run an exe to split TIFF files and finally another exe that uses a .net code to update database entries. The package works fine, but when scheduled as a Job, fails. Any idea why it would fail when run as a sql job?

Comment: There are probably some error entries that would provide information to answer this question. I suspect there is a permission issue; and have otherwise no care to play a guessing game.

Comment: Are you using a network path inside the package??

Comment: Hello, I have tried using the network park (like \\serverName\folderlocation\ etc. I have also used a drive letter like X:\folderlocation\. 
Both work fine if I run the Package using Visual Studio IDE, but will fail when scheduled as a step in the SQL JOB.

Comment: I found the issue was because the Job would be running under a different user ID. Once I applied the same privileges as the User ID under which the package ran successfully on local machine, the package was run successfully as a sql job. Thanks for your comments.